# Остановить выполнение основного алгоритма после прерывания

Tags: микроконтроллеры, stm32

Допустим, микроконтроллер в основном цикле с задержкой изменяет состояние ножки, к которой подключен светодиод.

```
while (1)
{
    // Проверка состояния флага прерывания (нажатие кнопки выключения)
    // Далее следует выполнение какого-то кода, если значение флага изменилось

    GPIOD->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD13;
    for (i = 0; i < 0x100000; i++);
    GPIOD->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_OD13;
    for (i = 0; i < 0x100000; i++);
}
```

В момент выполнения сработало внешнее прерывание - пользователь нажал кнопку выключения.

Так вот, возможно ли остановить выполнение кода в основном цикле по выходе из прерывания? То есть перейти к функции выключения, не дожидаясь завершения основной программы (циклов).

*STM32F4. Прошивка написана на CMSIS.*

Comment: Добавить проверку флага завершения во все циклы и дополнительно проверку после каждого что бы сделать break. И чисто теоретически если где то хранить адрес окончания цикла и обработчик прерывания имеет низший приоритет он может сам убедится что был прерван код именно в теле цикла и поменять адрес возврата в стеке таким образом, что бы при выходе из прерывания переход сразу произошел за его пределы. но там может быть очень много нюансов, надо детально изучать работу прерываний на вашем железе

Comment: Второй вариант интересный, но не очень безопасный, как мне кажется. К тому же требуется выполнять несколько задач одновременно (мигать двумя светодиодами, к примеру) - нужна многозадачность. Поэтому, вероятно, наиболее разумно будет использовать FreeRTOS.

Comment: Реализуйте аналог [setjmp/longjmp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longjmp) и возвращайтесь из обработчика в сохраненный контекст